# IE select2 4.0 control, lose the focus when press ENTER

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I have a problem with select2() (version 4) control when I use the IE.
When I press the ENTER or TAB key f to select the data from the list, I lose the focus over control. I need that the focus continue over the control and the user can  then selecting more data without press with mouse over control one more time for each input.

These problem only occurs with IE and not with Chrome or other Navigator

thank for your support and help!!

Comment: I'd recommend trying 4.0.1-rc.1, I believe this issue was fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! with de 4.0.1-rc.1 resolved the problem!!